# LONG DISPLAY OF WALLET ADDRESS - FLEXBOX REACT NATIVE

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I want to display **long type of address** which is described as truncated in the middle and **still keep 4 last character** of address, the address display will **take the width of its container.**

The example address is **"3njkd323njkfne4342kj21s3sjkdfbjkb"**

I tried to google it around, and I found a solution in the code and screen below.

But the problem is:

- **With width 40% or 50% or any width that can not include full address:** it still has gap between 2 text component (pink and red), which I dont want to have.
- **With width 70% (which means it can show all the letters of address)** it shows perfectly, no gap.

I thought the reason for the gap is because of the font of letters, depends on which character, or because it doesnt have enough space to include one more letter. I hope that you can understand the context I try to describe.

Im stuck for more than one week on this issue, if you have any idea or related keyword to this issues, I am really appreciate that.

[image: my code to display long address type]
[image: the result I got]

Comment: Aren't you able to deploy the app to something like CodeSandbox / share the whole code on GitHub?

Comment: @AifosSiPrahs hmm, its related to my work so I cant public the source code